# PDO transaction with exception

Tags: php, exception, pdo, transactions

Im having troubles resolving the following problem. Lets assume I have this:

```
class UserMapper{
 private $Pdo;

 function __construct(PDO $Pdo) {
   $this->Pdo = $Pdo;
 }

 function DeleteUser(UserID){
   try{
     $Pdo->beginTransaction();
     // some logic here which eventually throws exception
     $Pdo->commit();
   }
   catch(Exception $e){
     // exception thrown from the upper code goes here
     // I need to log error with further details into some event log, e.g. like this
     $EventLog->LogEvent("error occured" . $e->getMessage()); // 
   }
 }
```

The problem with the code above is that if the exception is catched then the Pdo is currently in the "beginTranstacion" state and therefore the log is not updated in the database.

Well, this could be fixed by commiting it in the catch event, but then it would cause problems when there is no exception.

Is there any solution to this I might be missing?

Comment: err... do I get you right that you are trying to save a log into **the same database that just failed you?**

Comment: `function DeleteUser(UserID)` the argument somehow is not a variable?

Comment: It is, I just typed the whole code by hand, so a type here:)
Yeah, to the same database, but there is no problem with that as the error is not PDOException, but rather my custom exception indicating something is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to $Pdo->rollback() to revert the database changes in the catch block and tell your user that something wrong.

Comment: I guess you are right.. How come id didnt occur to me before, I must be overworked..